# Element position fixed is related to parent instead to the viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**trying to achieve:**

position element in fixed right and top relative to the viewport

**what I am doing:**

- set position: fixed; to the element
- calculate the right and the top related and set it on the element

**what happen?**

- element any where is act as i wanted
- **but**  Element with the same styling (fixed position and right & top) in modal get positioned relative to he's parent (it's happen on bootstrap modal)

**code example**
element style:

```
.fixed-floater {
  top: 300px;
  right: 151px;
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
  min-width: 180px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

images:
[image: http://s3.postimg.org/u2kraeyzn/modal_error.png]

Comment: And is your modal by any chance an iframe ?

Comment: Can you post your html?

Comment: I think your modal has position:relative;

Comment: There's just no way, When setting `fixed` there's no space left for the element. Instead, it's positioned at a specified position relative to the ***screen's viewport*** and not moved if scrolled. If your element is doing something else, it's either not `fixed` or it's inside an iframe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**what happen (as i understand)**

modal container has (from bootstrap) defaults of transform: translate(0, 0);

by the **w3 specification** :

> element with position:fixed are always relative to the initial containing block.

[W3 Wiki](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning#Fixed_positioning)

> Some values of these properties result in the creation of a containing block

and

> For elements whose layout is governed by the CSS box model, any value other than none for the transform results in the creation of both a stacking context and a containing block. The object acts as a containing block for fixed positioned descendants.
>   [W3 Transform Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/)

So by the mentioned above, the Translate transform is setting the modal as "the initial containing block" for the fixed element inside him instead of the body.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR:

Override the specific modal's .modal-dialog with

```
transform: none;
```

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if there are any css keyframe animations written on any of its parent elements.

Try removing the class written for keyframe animations and check. It might work.

Answer (score 0):

I think this fixed related to modal div. check did you gave `position:relative` on modal div. if you did this remove the position:relative and make the position:relative to view port

like

```
.view-port{
position:relative
}
```